# Invalid username/password while connection oracle 11g through JDBC (110 % Sure that login credentials are correct)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I'm trying to connect to oracle 11g through JDBC, when I'm passing the username and password in the `getConnection()` method I can connect to the database just fine. But ,when I'm trying to take the input from their user and pass those as arguments.

I'm facing this error

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied.

I'm using a thin driver and this is how my code looks like:

```
Connection c=null;
private void getConnection() throws SQLException
{
    System.out.println("Enter login credentials");
    Scanner login=new Scanner(System.in);
    Object Username=login.nextLine();
    Object Password=login.nextLine();
    System.out.println("username"+Username);
    System.out.println("password"+Password);

    c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:(Omitted wantedly)/XE","Username","Password");
}
```

I'm able to connect to the database through sql command prompt with same credentials. I've also tried to unlock the user in which I'm in but it didn't help either. Please help !

Comment: In the code you posted, you are passing in the hard-coded string "Username" and "Password" for the username and password rather than the local variables Username and Password.  Is that the actual problem or was there a transcription error in posting your code sample.

Comment: @JustinCave  I'm passing the local variables "Username" and "Password" of type Object

Comment: I've figured out the problem. Thanks for the help anyway.. " The values of Username and Password shouldn't be passed inside double qoutes" and their datatype of Object's not acceptable in getConnection() they must be of type String.

Comment: @AmithAdiraju, you might consider adding the solution as an answer for the others to reap benefit of it, should they face the same situation. Comments can never serve as answers than an answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

just replace double quote from username and password.

> c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:(Omitted
>   wantedly)/XE",Username,Password);